# How to incorporate drop-down list within cells of shapefile attribute table using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, shapefile

A question has been brought to my attention. When working with a shapefile within either 10 or 10.1. Is it possible to create a python script or some sort of programming language to accomplish this task;

An attribute table consists of 3 columns with multiple rows. Is there a way to set a list for each column that may be used when clicking within each cell. I know this can be done within an edit session with domain and subtypes but can it be done just within the Attribute table itself. By way of scripting.

Reason, this would provide a streamline process for individuals who do not know much about ArcGIS and would save the process of an edit session and potential of misspellings and what not. The easy fix for a GIS person would be to just use Domains and Subtypes. But the question is, can it be done differently?

Comment: Are you asking if you can incorporate a drop-down list within cells of the shapefile attribute table?

Comment: Yes I am. and the drop-down list would be a set list of my own creation

Comment: Also, would I have issues with portability of shapefile and or possible feature class with the Script being "inside"?

Comment: I would be surprised if you could do this with Python.  This sounds more like a .NET/C# ArcObjects task.  I would think somwehere along the lines of "silently" initiating an edit session once the cell is clicked, becuase as far as i'm aware, you can't make edits on a cell by cell basis if you're not in an edit session.  You can make edits to an attribute table outside of an edit session, but the edits are carried out at the column level (e.g. Field Calculator).

Comment: Why not just use domains and subtypes?  That's what they're there for.

Comment: @Fezter His users are not well versed in ArcGIS.  I would personally spend the time and train them on doing this task.  Will there be multiple users editing the data at the same time?

Comment: I realize you can use Domains and Subtypes and that would be easily done with out question. But I was asked if it were to be possible to create a process without going into an edit session. I was quite skeptical without being a programmer. I said the same thing, "why not just use Domain and Subtypes". They are not hard to use at all. But they were/are asking or something specific that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to work with subtypes in a file geodatabase--you cannot create subtype definitions for shapefiles.  Look at [domains](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Domains_toolset/00170000001t000000/) and [subtypes](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Subtypes_toolset/0017000000mr000000/) on the ArcGIS help page to learn more.  The following script from ArcGIS 10.0 help shows how to create [subtypes](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000ms000000) programmatically:

```
# Name: ManageSubtypes.py
# Purpose: Create a subtype definition
# Author: ESRI

# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

try:
    # Set the workspace (to avoid having to type in the full path to the data every time)
    env.workspace =  "C:/data/Montgomery.gdb"

    # Set local parameters
    inFeatures = "water/fittings"

    # Process: Set Subtype Field...
    arcpy.SetSubtypeField_management(inFeatures, "TYPECODE")

    # Process: Add Subtypes...
    # Store all the suptype values in a dictionary with the subtype code as the "key" and the 
    # subtype description as the "value" (stypeDict[code])
    stypeDict = {"0": "Unknown", "1": "Bend", "2": "Cap", "3": "Cross", "4": "Coupling",\
                 "5": "Expansion joint", "6": "Offset", "7":"Plug", "8": "Reducer",\
                 "9": "Saddle", "10": "Sleeve", "11": "Tap", "12": "Tee", "13": "Weld", "14": "Riser"} 

    # use a for loop to cycle through the dictionary
    for code in stypeDict:
        arcpy.AddSubtype_management(inFeatures, code, stypeDict[code])     

    # Process: Set Default Subtype...
    arcpy.SetDefaultSubtype_management(inFeatures, "4")

except Exception, e:
    # If an error occurred, print line number and error message
    import traceback, sys
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print "Line %i" % tb.tb_lineno
    print e.message
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Yea I am we'll versed in domain/subtypes just not in programming. I was given a question and I am just in the process of answering it. Thanks for your time and it is appreciated. I would prefer them to use Domains and Subtypes bc that's what they are meant for.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a custom data entry form with Python. [This presentation](http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis10/upload/python/arcmap_and_python.pdf) by Mark Cederholm (also mentioned on this [ESRI blog post](http://betablogs.esri.com/beta/arcgis/2012/05/03/custom-wxpython-guis-an-approach-for-arcgis-10-1/) which has their own example) discusses how this can be done in two different ways, one using [Python Add-Ins](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000025000000) at 10.1 and another using [comtypes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/comtypes) at 10.0 and earlier.

[wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) is the GUI framework they suggest, though be aware it is not supported by ESRI. If you are looking for a more mature GUI development path that is supported by ESRI you'll want to use either .NET or Java.