# How to trigger a second drop-down list when selecting a coded value in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, domains

I am making a drop down list inside an attribute table of car makes, but want to have a list of models from the respective maker populate when I select a make.

Example:
I select Ford in my CAR_MAKE field
My CAR_MODEL field would populate with models that Ford makes.

Comment: Also related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44571/how-to-incorporate-drop-down-list-within-cells-of-shapefile-attribute-table-usin and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95055/app-for-collecting-points-with-hierarchical-legend-encoding